# ON OSX Why is the mongo command not recognised in my zsh shell on OSX even though it is exported in my .bash_porfile?

Tags: mongodb, macos

ON OSX No matter what tutorial I try or how ever many times I get GPT or BARD to take me through the installation of mongo through homebrew everything goes fine except for mongo getting into my path! I can not seem to point my terminal to mongo, ever!

My .zshrc file is this:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

I do have success connecting with compass but I need this to work with node and for 2 weeks now I have been constantly retrying, resetting the entire machine each time I do it so that the bash_profile and zshrc files are set back to just

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

I reload the shell and have even rebooted the machine but I am in a constant loop of it seemingly installing fine but then never being available as a command in my terminal.

```
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community

==> Fetching mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-arm64-6.0.6.tgz
Already downloaded: /Users/lewishornsby/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ab9dd9ef46c6f25730f2f5cb96ce513edce06aa144bfd476d6e4f5c0084f8dde--mongodb-macos-arm64-6.0.6.tgz
==> Installing mongodb-community from mongodb/brew
==> Caveats
To restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community after an upgrade:
  brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.6: 11 files, 200.8MB, built in 3 seconds
==> Running `brew cleanup mongodb-community`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
lewishornsby@Lewiss-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongo --version

zsh: command not found: mongo
```

It is driving me nuts, I know this has been asked before but every page I have found to answer it does not answer this question for me.

```
brew uninstall mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
brew cleanup
brew doctor
brew update
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
mongo --version
```

Is what I have tried and I was expecting the command `mongo --version` to show the version of mongo at 6.0.6 but i get "command not found"

Comment: Why does the subject line say "in my .bash_porfile?" if you're using Zsh and not Bash?

Comment: I read that zsh loads the bash profile on startup as well as its own.. I was trying combinations. Mongo is not installed anymore, I answered the question below. Thanks